# Experimenting inverting pictures with Octave

Tags: image, image-processing, octave

First time using Octave to experiment inverting an image. My filename is `LinearAlgebraLab1.m` and after I run the file with Octave I get error "error: no such file, '/home/LinearAlgebraLab1.m'"

However, before this, I was getting an error that my .jpg file couldn't be found. What should I change to have Octave run my script correctly without any errors?

```
%% import image
C = imread('MonaLisa2.jpg');

%% set slopes and intercepts for color transformation

redSlope = 1;
redIntercept = -80; 

greenSlope = -.75;
greenIntercept = 150; 

blueSlope = -.50;
blueIntercept = 200; 

%%redSlope = 1;
%%redIntercept = -80; 

%%greenSlope = -.75;
%%greenIntercept = 150; 

%%blueSlope = -.50;
%%blueIntercept = 200; redSlope = 1;


%% store RGB channels from image separately 

R = C(:,:,1); 
G = C(:,:,2); 
B = C(:,:,3); 

C2 = C; 
S=size(C);
m=S(1,1);
n=S(1,2);
%h=S(1,3);

%% change red channel

M = R; 
%%M2 = redSlope*cast(M,'double') + redIntercept*ones(786,579);
M2 = redSlope*cast(M,'double') + redIntercept*ones(m,n);
C2(:,:,1) = M2; 

%% change green channel

M = G; 
M2 = greenSlope*cast(M,'double') + greenIntercept*ones(m,n);
C2(:,:,2) = M2; 

%% change blue channel

M = B; 
M2 = blueSlope*cast(M,'double') + blueIntercept*ones(m,n);
C2(:,:,3) = M2; 


%% visualize new image
image(C2)
axis equal tight off
set(gca,'position',[0 0 1 1],'units','normalized')
```

Comment: Where do you upload your file to? Are you using some web service or a homework portal? Or do you mean you **run** your script in Octave?

Comment: I'm running my script in Octave

Comment: OK. So how are you running the script? From the command line? From the Octave interpreter? Through the GUI? Do you actually have a file `/home/LinearAlgebraLab1.m`? Are you using Linux? You need to be a lot more explicit when describing your situation, because it is simply not possible to help you if we don't understand the problem. Please [edit] your post to clarify the problem.

Comment: By the way, the second issue is easy: Octave will look for a file called `MonaLisa2.jpg` in the current directory. If it's not there, you'll get that error. Make sure you provide the complete path to your image file, or ensure that the image file is in  your current directory.